spring boot redirecting post request to Login
I'm currently developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Security, and I'm facing issues with securing a specific endpoint. Despite configuring security, authenticated users are unable to create books using the endpoint. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Controller Code:
package com.example.spring_security_course.controller;

import com.example.spring_security_course.entity.Book;
import com.example.spring_security_course.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.spring_security_course.service.BookService;
import com.example.spring_security_course.service.UserServices;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = bookService.findAllBooks();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(books);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}/home/books")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllUserBooks(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        try {
            UserEntity user = userServices.findUserById(userId);
            List<Book> books = bookService.getAllBookByUser(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(books);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(403).build();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> getBookById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Book book = bookService.findBookById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(book);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @PostMapping("/{userId}/home/books/create")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> createBook(@RequestBody Book book, @PathVariable Long userId) {
        UserEntity authenticatedUser = getAuthenticatedUser();

        UserEntity user = userServices.findUserById(userId);

        if (user != null && authenticatedUser != null && user.getId().equals(authenticatedUser.getId())) {
            book.setUser(user);
            Book createdBook = bookService.saveBook(book);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(createdBook);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }

    private UserEntity getAuthenticatedUser() {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            String username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
            return userServices.findByUsername(username);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Security Configuration:
package com.example.spring_security_course.security;

import com.example.spring_security_course.service.UserDetailsManagerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsManagerService userDetailsManagerService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                   .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().disable())
                   .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                       auth.requestMatchers("/register/**").permitAll();
                       auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
                       auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                       auth.requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("USER");
                       auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                   })
                   .formLogin(form -> form.permitAll())
                   .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsManagerService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

Issue:

When I try to create a book using the POST /api/v1/users/{userId}/home/books/create endpoint, it always returns a 200 ok response. and html respone with "please sign in "
enter image description here

I'm using Basic Authentication with valid USER credentials in Postman.

The method is annotated with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')"), and the user should have the correct role.


What I Have Tried:

Verified that the UserDetailsManagerService returns the correct roles for the user.

Ensured that the security configuration includes method-level security with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true).

Checked the logs for any clues, but nothing obvious stands out.
Questions:

Is there anything wrong with my security configuration or controller code that might be causing this issue?

Are there any additional steps I should take to debug why the @PreAuthorize annotation isn't working as expected?

How can I ensure that the authenticated user's roles are correctly recognized by Spring Security in this context?


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!



Once check the role you putted in the database. If you put just "USER" or "USER" in database in spring security side it is searching for "ROLE_USER" or "ROLE_ADMIN".
So try to update the database role as "ROLE_USER" or "ROLE_ADMIN"
